# Get button name inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a html button with runat=server tag, whoose Name has been set dynamically during run time.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnShowHideCols.Name = "some text here";
    }
```

the button HTML code is like below.

```
    <input id="btnShowHideCols" type="button" value="+/-" runat="server" onclick="return btnShowHideCols_onclick()" />
```

How Do I get the button name form inside the javascript function? can I get the sender of the event there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do this:

```
    <input id="btnShowHideCols" type="button" 
value="+/-" runat="server" onclick="return btnShowHideCols_onclick(this)" />
```

and than:

```
function btnShowHideCols_onclick(el) {
   el.getAttribute("name");
}
```

While writing something like `onclick=""` or `onchange=""` or any other event you can refer to current object with this.

Also, note that name will not be the same like in your code. It will be changed to something like ctl00$content$test, just the same as ID

Comment: Hi FAngel, this code runs but I dont get the Name which I am setting from code behind. I get the original name of the button like this --> GridViewParent_BtnShowHideCols

Comment: Sure. You can't get it. See the last paragraph in my answer. If element has runat="server" both name and id will containt names and ids of all parent elements with runat="server"

Answer (score 0):

Im quiet confused about what your trying to do..

Is this it:

```
document.getElementByid("btnShowHideCols").getAttribute("name")
```

^Will return the name

Then use this to send it to server.. Or am i wrong here?

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is good approach if you have no runat="server" in asp.net. But here will be no element with id="btnShowHideCols" as asp.net will change it and include ids of all runat="server" elements found up in tree.

Comment: Ahhh sorry i understand now:)